# Is this function homothetic?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, economics, homogeneous-equation, homothety

I need to check whether the following function is homothetic or not:
f(x,y)=x<sup>3</sup>y<sup>6</sup>+3x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>4</sup>+6xy<sup>2</sup>+9 for x,y ∈ R<sub>+</sub>

As it can be clearly expressed as a positive monotonic transformation of the homogeneous function xy<sup>2</sup> on R<sub>+</sub> therefore it must be a homothetic. But what's confusing me is that the ratio of its partial derivatives is not a homogeneous function of degree zero, which according to the textbook I'm using(Simon & Blume) is a condition that is satisfied by every homothetic function.